# Can we fake a DataServiceContext?

Tags: c#, wcf

I have a third party component that takes an Object that supports [DataServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.aspx) to pull the data. I figured [DataServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.aspx) has to do with [WCF Service](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd456779.aspx) (or someone should correct me if its Service with a URI in general).

In my scenario, my data is available in-memory through a List{T}. Would this be possible if I write a wrapper layer on top of the [List{T}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) by creating my own DataServiceContext-derived class and fake the service calls and just return the items from [List{T}](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) when queried ?

Does anybody see any issue with that approach ?

The component I am trying to use pulls portions of data from [DataServiceContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.services.client.dataservicecontext.aspx) .